# The Thing movie, the assimilation simulator

Tags: behind-the-scenes, the-thing-1982

Where can I find this software? Maybe this is not a full-finished software; if it is then do you know any references?

[image: assimilation]

Comment: What question are you asking? Are you trying to find the program used in the production of the movie that generated the graphics? Or are you asking how Dr. Blair wrote the program, in universe?

Comment: Program please. Im asking for it.

Comment: Computer screens and interfaces in TV Shows and Movies are very frequently made just for that film, specialized to display only what is needed for the the purpose. I'd be surprised if there is any actual program beyond just showing some fancy looking graphics. That is assuming that the software code was saved anywhere after production was done.

Comment: @Xantec I agree, but you never know.  Sometimes real interfaces and software are used to anchor the movie in the real world.

Comment: I don't think there's enough information here to answer it though

Comment: This answer would be on-topic if you were asking which program was used to produce this special effect (valid, but difficult to answer). However, I don't think that's the case: you seem to be asking for someone to tell you how to get _a fictional program_, which sounds off-topic to me.

Comment: That looks like alow-resolution and old, so that could be algol or basic but I wondered that executable is open for public access.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik - It isn't a real program, it was just inserted into the film in post-production.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The exact program doesn't really exist as has been stated

However, the closest thing you can probably get in reality would be a zombie outbreak simulator like [this](http://www.deathtech.com/zombies/) one.

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately, the software program doesn't exist.  It is a special effect added in post production.  The producer of the film, Stuart Cohen, has a blog, and one of the [entries](http://theoriginalfan.blogspot.com/2012/03/computers.html) is devoted to the computer programs in the movie.

> THE COMPUTERS
>
> THE THING, having been produced on the cusp of a digital universe, is a resolutely all-analog film, without a frame electronically processed. It is somehow fitting that the computers appearing in the movie are both mock ups, non-functioning props made out of bits and pieces, with the video display portion in both cases shot well after principal photography.
>
> Originally a much shorter moment containing less specific information, with Blair at the computer John essentially created a new scene in post-production built out of inserts. The only two pieces done during filming were those of Blair intently watching. John saw this as an opportunity to hammer home to the audience, in the simplest possible way, the idea of assimilation and it's consequences ( this became a primary concern as editing on the film  An analog endeavour, the program simulation was written by John and animated on film by fellow USC alumnus John Wash.
>
> None of us had any idea what this ought to  look like, so JC instructed John to make it as simple and familiar as possible by using video game graphics.  It was then transferred ( at a special 24 frame rate in order to avoid scanning lines) to U Matic 3/4 inch tape, fed back to a monitor, and photographed.

Cohen also says that MacReady's chess game is a real program for the old Apple Computer line.

Answer (score 2):

The program has just came into being:

[The Thing Simulator](https://elendir.itch.io/the-thing-simulator)